# How to unzip password protected zip files with apache nifi

Tags: passwords, zip, apache-nifi

In apache nifi I am not able to unzip zip-files in my workflow, because they are protected by a password. I know the password, it is the same for all Zips. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The current `CompressContent` processor does not provide for a way to accept a password, but you could work around this by using the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to invoke the `unzip` command on the command-line and populate the password in that command. I also raised a feature request Jira to enhance the processor [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7777).

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the password and it is the same for all the zipped files, you can easily use the UnpackContent processor. Select the package format and provide the password in text format like this.
[Configuring UnpackContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dmy8.png)

You can find details on this processor here - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UnpackContent/